# Is there any work being done to integrate GitHub repository issues with Stack Overflow discussions regarding the particular technology?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes there are parallel discussions on GitHub and on Stack Overflow regarding a particular issue. It would be nice if one can link the two in some way.

Comment: Like markdown links (i.e. HTML a elements)?

Comment: You surely don't mean adding one's entire repository to a question or answer, do you?

Comment: Issues raised on the repo that discusses the same issue being discussed on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The vast majority of true GitHub issues are bug reports or enhancement requests, which wouldn't be on topic here.

People misuse GitHub issues to ask questions about how to use the project, etc., and those aren't really issues. Those GitHub issues are the ones that tend to get re-posted to Stack Overflow.

When that happens on my repositories, I usually close the issue and point to the Stack Overflow question. Likewise, if I see bug reports or feature requests on Stack Overflow, I close them as being off topic. Stack Overflow really isn't the place for "discussions" about bugs or requested enhancements.